# Formal understanding of volatile semantic

Tags: c, language-lawyer, volatile, sequence-points

`5.1.2.3` defines the following:

> In the abstract machine, all expressions are evaluated as specified by
> the semantics. An actual implementation need not evaluate part of an
> expression if it can deduce that its value is not used and that no
> needed side effects are produced (including any caused by calling a
> function or through volatile access to an object).

The definition sounds a bit vague to me. I'm particularly concerned about *Sequenced before* definition and how (if) it is tied to `volatile`.

Consider the following function as an example:

```
void foo(volatile int* a, int *b, volatile int *c){
    *a = 1;
    *b = 2;
    *c = 3;
}
```

Basically I have 2 questions:

1. Is `*a = 1;` sequenced before `*c = 3`?
2. Is `*a = 1;` sequenced before `*b = 2;`?

If so, why?

Sequenced before is defined at `5.1.2.3` as:

> Sequenced before is an asymmetric, transitive, pair-wise relation
> between evaluations executed by a single thread, which induces a
> partial order among those evaluations

Comment: All of these are _sequenced-before_ one another regardless of `volatile`, because they are part of different statements in the same thread. But that has nothing to do with your first quote and `volatile` doesn't affect the _sequenced-before_ relation. What exactly is it that you are concerned about?

Comment: @user17732522 This is about `volatile` mostly. What properties are implied by accessing `volatile` variable except its pretty vague definition related to abstract machine.

Comment: What is it that you want to ask with the specific example and your reference to _sequenced-before_? The requirements on `volatile` access are in the the paragraphs above and below the one you posted.

Comment: @user17732522 I'm concerned about what "following rule the abstract machine" means in terms of evaluated specified by the semantic. The common use case of volatile is to prevent access from being optimized away. But does `volatile` impose any requirements on memory ordering? For example can compiler reorder 2 volatile write? Can compiler reorder volatile and non volatile write?

Comment: OK, you should ask it like that in your question, because _sequenced-before_ doesn't have much to do with that.

Comment: @user17732522 It's well defined that `A` happens-before `B` if `A` _sequenced before_ `B` or `A` _inter thread happens before_. How is it not related to?

Comment: _happens-before_ also doesn't generally tell you whether the compiler can reorder the emitted instructions. But an answer is already posted.

Comment: @user17732522 Hmm... What is the way to ensure compiler does not reorder instructions (not concerning architecture-related reordering) then?

Comment: `volatile` does achieve that (reordering between multiple `volatile` access), but that the evaluations are _sequenced-before_ one another is not a sufficient reason. The posted answer is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Further down in the same part of the "sequenced before" definition C17 5.1.2.3 §3:

> The presence of a sequence point between the evaluation of expressions A and B implies that every value computation and side effect associated with A is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with B.

This is crystal clear and leaves no room for interpretations.

In your code, every `;` marks a sequence point (end of a full expression). So it is without doubt sequenced from the top to the bottom and that much has nothing to do with `volatile`.

---

Another question is if the optimizing compiler is allowed to re-order the expressions. The C concept of "the abstract machine" is muddy and generally unhelpful, but what it says is:

> In the abstract machine, all expressions are evaluated as specified by the semantics. An actual
> implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its value is not used and
> that no needed side effects are produced (including any caused by calling a function or accessing a
> volatile object).
> /--/
> Accesses to `volatile` objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.

"The semantics" and "the rules of the abstract machine" refers (among other things) to the "sequenced before" part previously mentioned.

This can't very well get interpreted in any other way than that instruction re-ordering of `volatile` object access is forbidden.

However, the `*b=2;` expression is not `volatile` qualified. Here's where it gets muddy. One may read the quoted parts above as "no instruction re-ordering across `volatile` access is allowed". That is - `volatile` access must act as a memory barrier - which I think is the correct interpretation.

But as it happens, various CPU manufacturers implementing concurrent execution with pre-fetch and/or pipelining in multiple cores aren't necessarily digging this deep in the C standards during design. So the hardware might dictate how re-ordering will happen and then there's just so much the compiler vendor can do to fix it. Such hardware and the compiler for that hardware port might be a non-conforming implementation of the C language.

---

We may also note that the behavior of `volatile` changes slightly in the upcoming C23. A `volatile` *access* is now treated just as a `volatile` *object access*, meaning that stuff like `*(volatile int*)0x1234` didn't strictly speaking play by the same rules as `volatile int* ptr = (volatile int*)0x1234; ... *ptr`. This was a defect, there is a defect report, and it has been fixed in C23.

Comment: So it's safe to assume that `volatile` access acts as sort of "compiler barrier".  While it might still be possible that instrutions are reordered at runtime on a microarchitecture level.

Comment: @SomeName That seems to be the correct interpretation of the standard, but as mentioned in this answer not necessarily the interpretation that your CPU manufacturer did (if they ever read the standard to begin with). I don't think there are compilers that re-orders volatile access in relation to another volatile access, but there might be compilers/CPUs that reorders other access across a volatile access sequence point - which is arguably non-conforming.

Comment: "_which I think is the correct interpretation._": But I don't think e.g. GCC sees it that way, does it? I think I have seen GCC reorder non-volatile access across volatile access. For example https://godbolt.org/z/Grs5f4PKE.

Comment: @user17732522 Yeah indeed and I believe that is non-conforming behavior. And as soon as the standard is expressing something ambiguously, gcc has a tendency to pick the "ISO compliant Death Station" path, i.e always picking what would result in fastest possible code at the expense of program safety and ruggedness. Re-ordering instructions across `volatile` access on an embedded system can have disastrous consequences.

Comment: @Lundin: Such reordering would be legitimate (and sometimes useful) if an implementation is properly documented as suitable for use with execution environments or contexts where such reordering would not be observable.  Unfortunately, the authors of clang and gcc view the Standard's allowance for such behaviors in specialized implementatons as an invitation for such behavior in compilers that claim to be "general purpose".

Comment: @supercat A volatile access is always to be regarded as "observable" since the purpose of it might be to clear timing-sensitive flags, or to guarantee that some manner of time delay is executed, or to sequence side effects in relation to each other ("clear flag by first reading the status register then the data register") etc etc. They can't be re-ordered, period.

Comment: @Lundin: At the abstract machine level, that would be true, but if the implementation were to e.g. understand the meaning of 'disable interrupts' instructions, and knew that the execution environment would process `disable_interrupts(); x|=1; x|=2; enable_interrupts();` by loading `x` into a cache that wasn't observable via outside means, set the bottom two bits in the cached value, and then write it back just before re-enabling interrupts, the implementation could replace the middle operations with `x|=3;`.  It would be rare, of course, for implementations to be designed in such fashion...

Comment: ...but if in fact there were no way of observing the operations were performed on the cached value, such a transform could be useful and nothing would be gained by forbidding it.  My complaint with gcc and clang is the refusal of the maintainers to recognize that the Standard deliberately allows implementations or configurations intended for use exclusively in very specialized circumstances to behave in ways *that would make them unsuitable for most others*, and such allowance does not imply that any "optimizations" facilitated thereby are inappropriate in "general purpose" implementations.

Comment: @supercat I'm not sure what that example has to do with anything. If `x` is a `volatile` register then writing to it twice may have an entirely different meaning than writing to it once. Like: "Bit 0: enable peripheral. Writes to the rest of this register while this bit is not set will be ignored." Optimizing it from `x|=1; x|=2;` to `x|=3;` would change the meaning of the program and break it.

Comment: @Lundin: Incidentally, a volatile-related feature that would facilitate some useful optimizations would be a directive to indicate that volatile accesses performed in a designated block may be reordered *within that block*, so as to allow a sequence of functions that e.g. set and clear various bits to be consolidated in cases where the programmer knows that all possible orderings would *satisfy application requirements*.  IMHO, the Standard badly needs to recognize the existence of situations where observably different ways of processing code would all *satisfy requirements*.

Comment: @Lundin: Consolidation would only be allowed (absent directives inviting it) in cases where the implementation was documented as being unsuitable for use on execution environments where it might adversely affect program behavior.  On a stock 8031, for example, the states of addresses 0x00-0x7F would only be observable when bit 7 of address 0xA8 is set, but on an 8031 variant that supports DMA that might not be true.  An implementation for the 8051 that tracked the state of address 0xA8.7 and performed such consolidation should indicate in its documentation that it is...

Comment: ...in some configurations potentially unsuitable for some tasks involving DMA operations that could occur while bit 0xA8.7 is clear.  I don't know whether any implementations in fact perform such transformations, but the Standard goes out of its way to avoid forbidding optimizations that might be usable in obscure circumstances, on the presumption that compiler writers would only perform optimizations that were appropriate for the tasks for which their compilers were intended to be suitable.

Answer (score 2):

The semantics of volatile-qualified accesses are implementation-defined.  Many commercial compilers like MSVC are designed to refrain from ordering any memory operations across a volatile write, and limit actions that would reorder reads ahead of volatile reads to those which would consolidate them with previous reads, so a sequence like:

```
in_buff_ptr = my_buff;
in_buff_count = 4;
do {} while(in_buff_count);
doSomething(in_buff);
```

would be reliable if whatever might access the buffer would do so when accessing ordinary memory within a core that is cache-coherent with the core running the above code (note that on most embedded systems, all cores are cache coherent--if nothing else because that trait applies to all single-core systems).

The Standard would allow for the possibility that volatile accesses get processed by being enqueued somehow and processed by something outside the control of the executing code, a scenario that often applies to I/O devices.  Code would be required to behave as though actions were enqueued in the order specified, but the Standard would be completely agnostic with regard to what happens after that, including whether the actions occur in the specified sequence.  On some real-world systems, it would be entirely plausible that when executing a sequence of events like:

```
IOPINS = x; // IOPINS is volatile and when written sets the state of some I/O pins
y = IOPINS; // Reading IOPINS reports the clock-synchronized state of those pins
```

the read might yield the state of the pins just prior to when the write occurred.  If systems tried to read the instantaneous state of I/O pins directly, bad things might happen if a pin state were to change precisely as it was being read.  If code were doing something like "ADD R0,IOPINS" at just the wrong moment while R0 held 255 and the value on the pins was changing from 0 to 1, the physical bits within register 0 may be left in what's called a "metastable" state.  To avoid this, some systems pass port bits through what's called a "double synchronizer" which avoids this issue, but add a delay between when pins actually change state and when they're observed as changing state.

If one wants to perform reliable read-modify-write operations with such I/O devices, it's important to read and understand the hardware manuals for them.  Compiler writers generally won't have any way of knowing what kinds of I/O devices might be accessed via volatile-qualified operations, and what special precautions would be required to deal with them.  The best a compiler can do is generally to refrain from performing its own reordering across volatile-qualified accesses, and leave hardware issues up to programmers.

Comment: _The semantics of volatile-qualified accesses are implementation-defined._ Interesting... so without mentiontioning a specific implementation we can say pretty much nothing about the volatile object access

Comment: @SomeName: One can specify how such accesses behaved on general-purpose implementations when the Standard was written, and how they will behave on any implementation that makes a bona fide effort to be compatible with such treatment.  Some specialized implementations may benefit from doing something else, but unfortunately the Standard makes no distinction between implementations that follow common practice, and those that deviate from it (presumably because they have a good reason for doing so).

Answer (score 2):

Inside the abstract machine the standard uses to specify semantics, `*a = 1;` is before `*b = 2;`, and the latter is before `*c = 3;`.

Outside the abstract machine, the C standard specifies nothing about `*b = 2;` except that the observable behavior of the program must be the same as that of the abstract machine. The standard does not require an implementation to implement `*b = 2;` at all. There is not even any meaning for what `*b = 2;` is outside the abstract machine; the C standard does not even require that `*b` exist in any sense, let alone that it be after `*a = 1;` or `*c = 3;`.

Comment: _Inside the abstract machine the standard uses to specify semantics, *a = 1; is before *b = 2;, and the latter is before *c = 3;._ So the semantic means statements ordering as well as the side effect those statements produce. It was not obvious to me that semantic includes the relative ordering of statements.